# Updating element's innerText with input value on 'keyup'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practicing JS on this challenge from FrontEndMentor.io and just need assistance in figuring out how to get desired results.

My goal is to get the '0000 0000 0000 0000' on the class demo-numbers to update individually as the value is being typed. Example, you type '234' and it updates the card number to '2340 0000 0000 0000'... so on and so forth up to 16 digits.

[CodePen - Interactive Card Details]
https://codepen.io/jdubtheegreat/pen/JjvZMBJ?editors=0010

```
const demoName = document.querySelector('.demo-name');
const demoNum = document.querySelector('.demo-number');
const demoExpMM = document.querySelector('.demo-exp-mm');
const demoExpYY = document.querySelector('.demo-exp-yy');
const demoCvc = document.querySelector('.demo-cvc');

const cardName = document.getElementById('cardholder');
const cardNum = document.getElementById('card-num');
const cardExpMM = document.getElementById('exp-month');
const cardExpYY = document.getElementById('exp-year');
const cardCvc = document.getElementById('cvc');

addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (cardNum.value) {
    let demoNumArray = Array.from(document.querySelector('.demo-number').innerText);
    demoNumArray = demoNumArray.filter(function (entry) { return entry.trim() != ''; });
    const cardNumArray = Array.from(cardNum.value);

    for (let i = 0; i < cardNumArray.length; i++) {
      if (cardNumArray[i] !== undefined) {
        demoNum.innerText = demoNumArray.splice(demoNumArray[i], 1, cardNumArray[i]);
      } else {
        demoNumArray[i] = '0';
      }
    };
  };
});
```

```
<div class="card-front">
      <div class="demo-info">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meetjoewarren/learning-center/d05d53a12adeaa32e9b21bb033049fce570d460d/frontend-mentor/interactive-card-details-form-main/images/card-logo.svg" alt="Card Logo">
        <span class="demo-number">0000 0000 0000 0000</span>
        <span class="demo-name">Jane Appleseed</span>
        <span class="demo-exp">
        <span class="demo-exp-mm">00</span>/<span class="demo-exp-yy">00</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
        <span class="demo-cvc">000</span>
      </div>
      <div class="cardholder-content">
        <div class="card-form">
          <label for="cardholder">Cardholder Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="cardholder" name="cardholder" placeholder="e.g. Jane Appleseed" required>
          <label for="card-num">Card Number</label>
          <input type="text" id="card-num" name="card-num" placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000" maxlength="16" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" required>
          <label for="exp-date" class="min-content">Exp. Date (MM/YY)</label>
          <label for="cvc" class="min-content">CVC</label><br >
          <input type="number" id="exp-month" name="exp-month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" style="margin-right: 10px;" required>
          <input type="number" id="exp-year" name="exp-year" placeholder="YY" minlength="2" maxlength="2" required>
          <input type="text" id="cvc" name="cvc" placeholder="e.g. 123" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" required>
          <button type="submit" class="submit">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*The code that is commented out in the JS section on GitHub updates the card except it erases the entire string on the demo card as it's typed*

TIA for any assistance provided!

Comment: Good luck with the user editing the card number starting from the middle ;) PS can you create a [mcve] so we don't have to guess the HTML etc?

Comment: Just updated my post to have minimal HTML. The full setup is on CodePen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use method `padStart` or `padEnd` to fill the cardNum value with 0 digit until the needed size

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```js
const demoNum = document.querySelector('.demo-number');
const cardNum = document.getElementById('card-num');

cardNum.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (cardNum.value) {        
    demoNum.innerText = cardNum.value.padEnd(16, '0').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
  };
});
```

```css
.demo-number {
  border: solid blue;
}

#card-num {
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-front">
  <div class="demo-info">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meetjoewarren/learning-center/d05d53a12adeaa32e9b21bb033049fce570d460d/frontend-mentor/interactive-card-details-form-main/images/card-logo.svg" alt="Card Logo">
    <span class="demo-number">0000 0000 0000 0000</span>
    <span class="demo-name">Jane Appleseed</span>
    <span class="demo-exp">
          <span class="demo-exp-mm">00</span>/<span class="demo-exp-yy">00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-back">
  <span class="demo-cvc">000</span>
</div>
<div class="cardholder-content">
  <div class="card-form">
    <label for="cardholder">Cardholder Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="cardholder" name="cardholder" placeholder="e.g. Jane Appleseed" required>
    <label for="card-num">Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="card-num" name="card-num" placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000" maxlength="16" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" required>
    <label for="exp-date" class="min-content">Exp. Date (MM/YY)</label>
    <label for="cvc" class="min-content">CVC</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="exp-month" name="exp-month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" style="margin-right: 10px;" required>
    <input type="number" id="exp-year" name="exp-year" placeholder="YY" minlength="2" maxlength="2" required>
    <input type="text" id="cvc" name="cvc" placeholder="e.g. 123" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" required>
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the result I was looking for (minus the space every 4th char but I am sure I can figure that out). Thanks for the quick reply, learned something new!

Comment: to add space every 4th character you can use `.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ')` i edit my reply with this element

Comment: This works, thank you. I was using `.match(/.{1,4}/g)` for it before. I do have one last question if you don't mind, how would one go about having that same styling on an input value? I used the match method and after the first two sets of 4 the next set spaces out after every letter. You can check my CodePen if that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

My version

https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/bGMjqgj

```js
const zeroes = "0000 0000 0000 0000";
cardNum.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const placeholder = [...zeroes];
  if (cardNum.value) {
    const digits = [...cardNum.value];
    let cnt = 0;
    placeholder.forEach((_, i) => {
      if (cnt>=digits.length) return;
      if (placeholder[i] !== " ") placeholder[i] = digits[cnt++];
    })
  }
  demoNum.textContent = placeholder.join("");  
});
```